# Setting up a string search engine for certain set of files

Tags: full-text-search, elasticsearch, search-engine

I need to set up a full text search engine to perform string search in large number of files that are from various sources. I am trying to make use of open source search engine that are used for web based search. Can i use those for my requirement? Can anyone guide to any choices?

I found elastic search is a good option. But, Is there any way to clear contents of engine periodically?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Elasticsearch will work well for what you are trying to do. The easiest way to clear your data periodically is probably to just delete the index and then rebuild it.